# I want to login with twitter in Cakephp2.5.4

Tags: php, twitter, cakephp-2.5

I am a new in cakephp 2.x platform. Now I am trying to connect my application login with twitter. I get lots of tutorial from the net. But all are not specified exactly for better understanding.

I'm searching for some docs or examples on CakePHP and logging in with Twitter.

If I use this program, do I have to download the Opauth CakePHP plugin? Is this plugin a must or is it optional, if I didn't use this plugin can I run this program?

Please show me some good tutorials for this program.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried this tutorial given by Mifty - http://miftyisbored.com/complete-social-login-application-tutorial-cakephp-2-3-twitter-facebook-google/
Please try this, it will help you.